# Changing the Title bar

Tags: android, android-activity, titlebar

In my program I have several activities. When I run the program, I have the name of application in Title bar (top of the screen).

How can I change this title with any text that I wish? I want to change the text of it for each activity.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title bar displays the property defined in `android:label=""` for each .  If you'd like it to display the same name no matter the activity you could use `android:label="@string/title_bar"` which should point to a string that you've defined in res/values/strings.xml.

Comment: Sorry, that property is found in the AndroidManifest.xml for each `Activity` defined.

Comment: This also allows the strings you define to be easily translated without getting into your source.

Answer (score 4):

Put

setTitle(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME_HERE);

under onCreate method of your desired activity.